# Replace with regular expression in powershell script not working

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to remove all the comments from JSON file using regular expression with following pattern:

```
$mytext="{/* anytext */  'name':'myname'}"
$mytext -replace /\/\*.+?\*\/|\/\/.*(?=[\n\r])/g,''
```

The expression is working fine in JavaScript, but not in PowerShell.

Comment: Wrong syntax, use `-replace '/\*.+?\*/|//.*(?=[\n\r])', ''`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert to JSON with comments from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066978/convert-to-json-with-comments-from-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

1. You haven't quoted the pattern
2. PowerShell doesn't wrap patterns with `/` and `/g` (global flag) is not necessary as `-replace` will use it by default.

I also added `\s*` to remove unnecessary whitespace after the comment

Try:

```
$mytext="{'foo'='bar' /* anytext */  'name':'myname'} {'foo'='bar' /* anytext */  'name':'myname'}"
$mytext -replace '\/\*.+?\*\/\s*|\/\/.*(?=[\n\r])'
```

Output:

```
{'foo'='bar' 'name':'myname'} {'foo'='bar' 'name':'myname'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for quick answer guys. I have tried both the patterns and it works well, the only issue i am facing for some places it move the value text in next line which makes json invalid. 

"bootstrap": {
        "base": "${app.dir}",
        "manifest": "bootstrap.json",
        "microloader": "b
        ootstrap.js ",      "
        css ": "
        bootstrap.css "     },      "
        output ": {         "
        base ": "
        $ {
            workspace.build.dir
        }
It should be like
"bootstrap": {`enter code here`
        "base": "${app.dir}",
        "manifest": "bootstrap.json",
        "microloader": "bootstrap.js",
        "css": "bootstrap.css"
    },
/* *anytext */
"output": {
        "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}"
    },
```